# Completeness property of R

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum, upper-lower-bounds

I was reading up on the completeness property of **R** that sets it apart from **Q**

It has been stated in 2 ways which are

1. Every non empty subset of **R** which is bounded above has a supremum in **R**
2. Every non empty subset of **R** which is bounded below has an infimum in **R**

Now this is very clear. The problem lies in what these 2 statements are followed by which has been marked in red in the given picture. It says that these 2 properties are equivalent in the sense that **one implies the other**. How is that even possible?

according to thus language, they r suggesting that 1. implies 2. i.e. if supremum exists than infimum exists too and vice versa which is clearly not the case. Am i interpreting it wrong?

Can someone help urgently plz!
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Take a non-empty subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}$ that is bounded below.

Let $T$ be the set $S$ where every element is multiplied by $(-1).$

Therefore, $T$ is bounded above.

By assumption, $T$ has a supremum.

Therefore, $S$ has an infinum.

Comment: So do they mean to say that by using one of these properties, we can prove the other? Like using the supremum property, we can prove the infimum property, right?

Comment: @RandomlyReal Exactly.  And that is exactly the strategy used in my answer.  I assumed that one of the properties existed and used it to show that the other property must then also exist.

Comment: Yes, now it's clear to me. Thank you!!